# Combine a VLOOKUP and SUMIFS calculation into one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need some help streamlining calculations I have done in 2 parts into 1 cell.

Table 1 has Quarter, Name, Revenue
eg.

```
1, John, 100
2, John, 200
2, Jane, 300
3, John, 400
3, John, 350
```

VLOOKUP Table2:

```
100 | 300   | 10
301 | 600   | 30
601 | BLANK | 50
```

What I've done originally is create a column next to the revenue (D) against the VLOOKUP to get the result in column 3 
i.e = `VLOOKUP (Table1C1, A1:C3,3,TRUE)`

Then use SUMIFS against quarter and name to sum the values found in the VLOOKUP. How do I combine these together?

I've tried:

```
VLOOKUP(SUMIFS(Table1C:C,Table1A:A,1,Table1B:B,John),Table2A1:C3,3,TRUE)
```

This partially works but doesn't run the VLOOKUP against each revenue that fits the conditions before returning the assigned value and instead combines the revenue before referencing against the VLOOKUP.

I've created a dummy version if it helps
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hl-TLyfJowcnJU-h6mPgyJ5xUybtOaKb4xmyJozsJow/edit?usp=sharing

My attempt in yellow and combined `VLOOKUP(SUMIFS())` in green which don't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP($C$2:$C$14,Sheet2!$A$1:$C$3)*($B$2:$B$14="John")*($A$2:$A$14=1))
```

See image for reference

[image]

***Note:*** Data in `Column A` of `Sheet2` must be in ascending order. For details on `LOOKUP` see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb).

Comment: Thanks @Mrig. It works,  but is there another way to solve this without the need to sort the table? The data will be combined together via Power Query/Query Editor in Power BI. (Sorting can be done post query) but ideally I'd like it to calculate with the initial table as is. Cheers

Comment: @JasonTran - One of the drawbacks of using `LOOKUP` function is that the data has to be sorted. And as far as your scenario is concerned, `LOOKUP` fits better.

Comment: Hmm. What about nested if statements + SUMPRODUCT instead?

Comment: @JasonTran - Here `SUMPRODUCT` is not an issue. It's the `VLOOKUP` that's making solution complicated. `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX/MATCH` are not able to get results in array that why `LOOKUP` is used.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I'll keep chipping away to see if another solution exists in the meantime

Comment: @Mrig, curiously `VLOOKUP($C$2:$C$14,Sheet2!$A$1:$C$3,3,TRUE)` **can** be used in an array formula and delivers an array of 13 values. (For example it can be used as an alternative way of assigning cells `D2:D14`) However, when substituted for the `LOOKUP` used in the `SUMPRODUCT` of your answer, the `VLOOKUP` is treated as a scalar.  Further, this scalar is not necessarily the first element of the array.

Comment: @JasonTran it is the lookup table that needs to be sorted to use `LOOKUP` function, not Table 1. The same requirement applied to your attempted use of the `VLOOKUP` function with `TRUE` as its final argument (and you were conforming to that requirement already).

Comment: @DMM Thanks. It looks like SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP proved to be the answer I was looking for. Table 1 remains unchanged, VLOOKUP table is sorted and the values match up to my 2 step method.

Comment: @JasonTran `SUMPRODUCT((LOOKUP(...)...)` (as proposed by @Mrig) gives you the correct answer to your problem. `SUMPRODUCT((VLOOKUP(...)...)` will either give you `#VALUE!` or incorrect results dependent on whether it is used as a normal formula or an array formula.